# WSO2 IS SCIM user schema extension. How to define and map multi-valued attributes

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.1 and I'd like to define multi-valued attribute:

```
....
{
"attributeURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:wso2:1.0:wso2Extension.vultPerson.mailAlternateAddress",
"attributeName":"mailAlternateAddress",
"dataType":"string",
"multiValued":"true",
"multiValuedAttributeChildName":"null",
"description":"Some attribute",
"schemaURI":"urn:scim:schemas:extension:wso2:1.0",
"readOnly":"false",
"required":"false",
"caseExact":"false",
"subAttributes":"null" 
},
...
```

I mapped this attribute in urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0 dialect to LDAP (primary user store) atrribute mailAlternateAddress (my LDAP has this attribute in one of UserEntryObjectClass'es). I tried to provision user by SCIM API. User was created, all simple attributes from extension were created too, only mailAltrernateAddress not. I tried to send this attribute as:

```
....      
"mailAlternateAddress": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "value": "a.a"
        }
....
```

and as:

```
...
"mailAlternateAddress": ["a.a","b.b"]
...
```

I received good responses to SCIM requests.

I tried mappings:

```
urn:scim:schemas:extension:wso2:1.0:wso2Extension.vultPerson.mailAlternateAddress -> mailAlternateAddress
and
urn:scim:schemas:extension:wso2:1.0:wso2Extension.vultPerson.mailAlternateAddress.work -> mailAlternateAddtress
```

Both with the same result.

BTW, according to core SCIM schema, **emails** attribute is mapped to LDAP **mail** attribute (this mapping is in WSO2 IS destribution) but this mapping  doesn't work too, **mail** attribute isn't created.

What am I doing wrong?
One more question. Could I define canonical values for multi-valued attribute in scim-user-schema-extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in class

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.utils.AttributeMapper
```

There are strange limitations. At first I rewrote method **getClaimsMap** and now it works as expected.

I'm sorry for my English.